# How to whitelist my IP address for s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to only allow my IP address to access my S3 bucket. I am using it for hosting a static react app. I have wrote the bucket policy but I am still getting the 403 Forbidden error when trying the url. 
I believe it may have to do with just putting in the wrong IP. I am using a mac and am getting it through system preferences > network > advanced > TCP/IP > IPv4 Address.

My bucket policy is below:   where myIP is the ip I am trying to whitelist

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "myIP"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's most likely your internal network IP unless your Mac is connected directly to an Internet connection without any router in between. Go here to get your public IP address, which is what you will need to whitelist https://www.whatsmyip.org/

Comment: Thanks @MarkB , this solved my issue